# java enter to another thread when using loop with sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I need a help I'm trying to make client server app for copying files in java... I've got MainWnd object which creates TCPServer object and on send button it will create TCPClient object which send initial data to opponent TCPServer and will open given number of Listen Thread (let it be *n*) (this Listen threads are here only because they accept a file) (every thread listen on different port which send back to TCPClient) TCPClient then creates *n* other TCPClients threads which send the file... This I've got and it's running. Problem is, that file receiving can be interrupted by receiver when he click on button Interrupt. I can't get information of this interruption to the receiver's TCPServer thread, which should kill this *n* threads which are downloading the file.

I think the problem is in TCPServer, where is infinit loop, but the Socket in this will cause blocking of loop  so I can't enter to Connection class and kill this *n* threads.

**TCP SERVER**

```
public void setSendInterruption() {
    this.interruptedSending = true;
    //c.setSendInterruption();
}

public TCPServer(int port, int socketNums, Map<Byte, LinkedList<Byte>> realData, File file, int fileLength) {
    this.serverPort = port;
    this.socketNums = socketNums;
    if(file != null)
        this.file = file;
    if(fileLength != -1)
        this.fileLength = fileLength;
    if(realData != null)
        this.realData = realData;

    if(tmpData != null)
        this.tmpData = tmpData;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try { 
        System.out.println(this.getId());
        listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort); 

        System.out.println("server start listening... ... ...");

        while(true) {
            if(interruptedSending)
                System.out.println("Here I never come");
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept(); 
            Connection c = new Connection(clientSocket, socketNums, realData, file, fileLength); 
        } 
} 
catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Listen :"+e.getMessage());} 
}
```

**Connection**

```
while (true)
                {
                    byteRead = input.read();
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                    if(interruptedSending) {
                        TCPClient tcpClient = new TCPClient(clientSocket.getPort(), clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                        tcpClient.sendInterruptedData();
                        interruptedSending = false;
                    }
                    char lowChar;

                    if(byteRead == -1) {
                        break;
                    } else
                        lowChar = (char)byteRead;

                    lowData += lowChar;

                    if(lowData.length() >= 2) {
                        if (lowData.substring(lowData.length()-2).compareTo("//") == 0) {
                            break;
                        } else if (lowData.length() > 6) {
                            byteData.add((byte)byteRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

In connection there is more lines, but they are only mainly parsing a protocol.
Thanks a lof for your help. I hope I wrote it clean...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand each Connection has a Thread that runs it. You want to interrupt each of these threads but can't do that from within the threads because they are stuck in input.read().

If that is what you meant, just do this:

In the constructor of Connection save the Thread, so you can access it later.
Make a killThread()-Method or therelike, so you can access the thread from the outside:

```
public void killThread() {
    thread.interrupt(); //thread is the thread you saved in the constructor
}
```

When you want to kill the Connection-thread call killThread(). This will cause the Thread to throw a java.lang.InterruptedException, wherever it is at the moment.
This one you can either ignore (since you want the thread to die anyways) or you encase the whole while-loop with a

```
try {
    //your loop
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    return;
}
```

which will end the thread nicely without throwing the exception out.